# Which is a better way - store `const reference` vs `boost::shared_ptr<Class>` as a member variable

Tags: c++, boost

```
class ClassOne : boost::noncopyable
{
};

class ClassTwo : boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    ClassTwo(const ClassOne& one)
        : m_one ( one ) {}

private:
    const ClassOne& m_one;
};

class ClassThree : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    ClassThree(boost::shared_ptr<const ClassOne> one)
        : m_one ( one ) {}

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<const ClassOne> m_one;
};

class ClassFour : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    ClassFour(const boost::shared_ptr<const ClassOne>& one)
        : m_one ( one ) {}

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<const ClassOne> m_one;
};
```

Question> During codereview, I was told that the code (similar as `ClassTwo`) should be replaced by the code (similar as `ClassThree`) because storing a const reference to outside class is NOT safe.

Is that true?

Thank you

Comment: That would completely depend on the code using these classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Const reference and `shared_ptr` models two similar, but different concepts.

If you have a const reference, you "know" something, you can inspect this thing (through const methods) but you can't change this thing, and even more important, this thing might vanish any time: you don't own it.

On the other hand, `shared_ptr` models a shared **ownership**. You own the object pointed by the pointer. You can change it and it wont be destructed, unless every owner gets destructed.

Returning const reference to a private member is safe; accepting such a reference is a different thing. You have to make sure the reference remains valid.

`shared_ptr` is easier to handle but it's a more expensive solution.

Regarding the exact dynamics, read the **[manual of `shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)**

Comment: +1 in general I prefer smart ptrs because they manage their resource internally, allowing us to follow the rule of zero. I know thats not the case of the question (In the question the object is inmutable), but is a good rule of thumb I think

Comment: @Manu343726 unique_ptr is usually better. Also, references don't necessarily inhibit Rule-Of-Zero (e.g. if the type is not supposed to be copyable), with the lifetime issues being roughly the same as when using non-owning pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I think erenon has a good writeup.

I'd like to add a little from the pragmatic angle:

- const reference members make classes non-copyable (in fact, they could be copyable, but generation of default special members is inhibited (except for the destructor)
- shared_ptr, on the other hand, make stuff inherently copyable (with shallow-clone semantics). This turns out to be really useful in functors where state will be kept/passed along. Boost Asio is a prime example, because logical threads of execution meander across threads and the lifetime is largely unpredictable.
- I suggest using a `shared_ptr<const T>`; This adds *immutability* in the context of *sharing*. You will need to clone the object pointed to replace it with a changed version, and the shared object will not be modified through the `shared_ptr<const T>`